# Using context variables to write the user's car registration

Tags: ibm-cloud, watson-assistant

In watson-conversation, I have reached a point where I ask the user their car number (registration), which follows this format: `0000BBB` (4 numbers, 3 letters).

I want to type that to the user like:

`User: "My car id is 0123asd"`

`Watson: "Okay so your car id is this one: 0123asd"!`

I have tried defining an entity `#carId` with some examples, but every time I input something with that format (`0000BBB`), it shows "irrelevant".

If the chat detects `#carId`, respond with `Okay so this is your carId! @exampleCarId` (I have some examples like `5487qwe`, or `8521rty`, I thought the machine learning below that would learn the "pattern").

[image]

And my `#carId` has these examples:

[image]

I know I am missing something! Do I need to code anything? I think it's not necessary. I tried to save it on a `sys-number` but it does not work as it is not a "number".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most developers would consider he car ID an entity (denoted by @). IBM Watson Assistant allows to define so-called [dictionary-based entities](https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/assistant/entities.html#create-dictionary-based). One form of such an entity is pattern-based. Thus, you would define a pattern of 4 digits and 3 letters.

You could have an intent (denoted by #) that identifies that a user inputs the car ID. In the dialog node you could match against the intent and then assign the matched entity for the actual ID to a variable.

The linked documentation has examples.

Comment: I've tried and I do not seem to get it. As patterns, and following the documentation, only 5 patterns can be given. (I am trying to do it strictly without coding anything, which is not a problem but it is a requirement for now).

Comment: What do you mean with "only 5 patterns"? And what do you mean with coding? It is a specification, e.g., `\d\d\d[A-Za-z][A-Za-z][A-Za-z]`.

Comment: In the documentation you provided me (and I am thankful for that!) there is "Value: burger", so the "synonyms, instead you can choose "patterns", and it only lets you write down 5 of them. I am entirely doing this with the `intents`, `entities`and `dialog`provided. Where do you assign the `\\d\d\d[A-Za-z][A-Za-z][A-Za-z]`. I cannot see where. Sorry for bothering you!

Comment: For entities you can enter either synonyms or a pattern. Put the string above as pattern.

Comment: Oh! That was it! Okay! It gets it now! Though the intent shows as irrelevant every time. But I'll manage! Thanks a lot!